# How to make sure every connected client receives the message published with SocketIO?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I need to make sure that every connected client receives the event sent with SocketIO on a NodeJS server.

Is there any way to make sure this happens? Or does SocketIO does that already?

Else, what is the concept I'm looking for.

Comment: usually you don't have to check if it's delivered, socket.io does some internal checking and errors are emitted if something went wrong. But if you add some additional behaviors and need to check that all clients received the message try to work something out like an verify message received event.

Comment: But I have cases where clients, even though connected, didn't receive events. Why could this possibly be?